# javascript hyperlink

Tags: javascript

Hi I have written a abcd.ftl page which is beeing called in another defg.page 
The abcd.flg page has the fallowing code

```
 <div class="partnerOptInBox">
        <div id="optInContent">
            <form name="partnerOptIn">
                <h4>Want the Latest</h4>
                <p class="pad10Top">${partnerOpt.translation}</p>
                <div class="pad10Top">
                <input type="radio" name="questionAnswer['${partnerOpt.questionId}']" value="${partnerOpt.getAnswers()[0].answerId}" class="radioButton" /> <label for="questionAnswer['${partnerOpt.questionId}']" class="formLabel pad20Right">Yes</label> <input type="radio" name="questionAnswer['${partnerOpt.questionId}']" class="radioButton" value="${partnerOpt.getAnswers()[1].answerId}" /> <label for="questionAnswer['${partnerOpt.questionId}']" class="formLabel">No</label>
                </div>
                <div id="optInError" class="formError" style="display:none;">Oops... your request did not go through, please try again.</div>
                <div class="pad15Top">
                    <a href="javascript:submitOptIn();"><img src="images/theme/btn_opt_in_submit.gif"/></a>
                </div>                         
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
function submitOptIn() {
    $('optInError').hide();
    dataString = $('#partnerOptIn').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        data: dataString,
        url: partnerOpt.do,
        timeout: 30000,
        type: "POST",
       success: function(html){
            var newHtml = "<h4>Thank you</h4><p>We appreciate your time to respond to our request.</p>";
            $('#optInContent').html(newHtml);
    },
        error: function(){
            $('#optInError').show();
        }
    });
}
</script>

        </div>
    </div>
```

But when I am clicking the submit button on this page its throwing a error saying "javascript:submitOptIn" not defined can any one please let me know what would be the reason for this error asap please THank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should put the script tag in the head of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't javascript have to be enclosed in {literal}?

Answer (score 0):

All jQuery scripts should be placed inside the "document.load" event to ensure that the DOM has loaded. Try to place your scripts inside:

```
$(function() {

   // place your scripts here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code DOES work on IE6, IE7, FF and Chrome...
It's all the code you posted in the defg.page, or are you calling it from the abcd.ftl page?

Comment: the defg page is the parent page where I wrote something like 
<#include "abcd.ftl">

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:submitOptIn();">...</a>
```